# Deserialization backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I am trying to deserialize "SomeClass" with an older version of an application. I get this below exception

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups. This usually indicates a problem in the Formatter.

Deserialization throws exception when I **serialize version 0.9** and try to **deserialize using version 0.8**. I thought the `OptionalField` attribute would do the trick, but it didn't.

```
// Version 0.8
[Serializable()]
class Foo{
  Bar b;
} 

// Version 0.9
[Serializable()]
class Foo{
  Bar b;
  [OptionalField]
  Zoo z;
}
```

Given that I cannot change version 0.8, how should I add more state to Foo object such that previous versions can deserialize whatever they can?

Any pointer will be really appreciated.

**Update 1**
Bar and Zoo are other classes which are serializable and contains Hashtables and other serializable stuff. Everything is serializable in those classes.
Also, I don't have any struts.

Comment: Whether the field is optional or not is irrelevant here - the fact is that serialization doesn't work across versions, AFAIK; that's not to say you _can't_ add members, of course you can, but, for instance, I can't just define a verbatim type and deserialize items serialized with the existing - something to do with the assemblies, or the types `token`, I think.

Comment: kareph, what is the real type of `Zoo` ? I remember some types (arrays) just didn't work right.

Comment: Would you be willing to use xml serialization rather than binary serialization? That would be more version-safe.

Comment: @code4life - we want to stick to binary serialization unless xml serialization is faster, which I doubt. @Henk- I updated the post.

Comment: XML serialization isn't more version safe. The CLR stores about the same amount of versioning information in the serialized representation as it does for binary, the only difference is that you can see it. You're still going to end up using a custom binder or some other hack (like manual XML->object mapping!) if you run into a version issue down the road.

Comment: kprobst: Clarification: I'm talking about serializing the content to xml instead of binary, not the actual serialization assemblies themselves. The xml content (derived via xml serialization) would be version-neutral. Of course if the schema changes, then the serialization process would be affected, but then, the same challenge applies to binary serialization in that situation.

Comment: @karephul: xml serialization will definitely be slower.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First, never NEVER use the CLR's serialization functions for anything that resembles long-term storage. We make that mistake usually once, put objects in a blob database field and pat ourselves in the back thinking we're clever. And then the CLR gets a patch or our assemblies change versions and you're screwed. So don't do it.

If you still want to do it, the best way to manage the problem is to create your own `SerializationBinder` that looks something like this:

```
public sealed class CustomBinder : SerializationBinder {

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName) {

        Type typeToDeserialize = null;

        if (typeName.IndexOf("SomeType") != -1) {
            typeToDeserialize = typeof(Foo.Bar.Bax.NewType);
        }
        else if (typeName.IndexOf("SomeOtherType") != -1) {
            typeToDeserialize = typeof(Foo.Bar.Bax.SomeOtherNewType);
        }
        else {
            // ... etc
        }

        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}
```

Set the `Binder` property of the formatter you're using prior to deserializing so that it overrides the defaults.

Note that I'm not offering a drop-in solution here, I'm recommending how to solve the problem. Once you've converted out of whatever you're doing, investigate other serialization technologies like protobuf, or write your own. Either way you should never rely on the CLR for long-term serialization support.

Comment: does your 'NEVER' comment also apply to XML serialisation? Seems to me that with DataContract and DataMember there is good control over the generated structure. Would be interested to get your opinion on that.

Comment: No but the binary serializer is not suited for long term serialization. It is best suited for pumping bytes over the wire, in for example, a client-server application. WebForms for example uses it.

Answer (score 4):

If constructors for each version are compatible (e.g. there is a parameterless or `Foo(Bar b)` constructor for both versions) you can call

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.AssemblyFormat = Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
```

Before deserializing your stream.

Answer (score 4):

As an advisory to people investigating this issue "before it is too late"... I strongly advise against persisting via BinaryFormatter. It is OK for transient transfer between 2 app-domains that are in sync, but that is about it IMO. Other serialization tools exist that don't have these issues. In terms of binary, protobuf-net is a pretty reasonable option - allowing add/remove/rename etc without pain.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that one way to do this would be to have a versioned object, that way you could try deserializing the object using the latest version. If that didn't work, step back a version until it's successful. Then once you have your object, update it to the latest version of the object and use default values for any fields you don't have data for.

Comment: If we downgrade (result of rollback) our application then we'll have fields which are missing (instead of data missing); anyways what you are saying is what it should be.

Comment: I know that's what C programmers use to do. I thought we are programing at very high level of abstraction and this might be standard problem. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

The `optional field` attribute should have done the trick. Can you post the actual classes that you are trying to serialize.

You could try these things first -

convert `structs` if any to `classes`

try `Soap Serialization` instead of `binary serilization`

Comment: did u try soap serialization?