# Deserializing BinaryFormatter Files with earlier version produces SerializationException.

Tags: .net, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I am having trouble deserializing moderately complex objects produced by serialization from a later version of my program. I get an exception of:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled
Message=The ObjectManager found an invalid number of fixups. This usually     indicates a problem in the Formatter.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.Samples.TestV1.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\vts\CS\V1 Application\TestV1Part2\TestV1Part2.cs:line 29
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
...
```

This has to do with trying to deserialize objects that have changed (added members) in later versions with an older version.  However, Microsoft states that it should work because of VTS.  See:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752(v=vs.110).aspx

They provide an example, that unmodified, does indeed allow you to deserialize more recent classes with an older version.  See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a6c3wzt(v=vs.110).aspx

However, as hinted here:  [Deserialization backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381928/deserialization-backwards-compatibility) with the comment,

```
kareph, what is the real type of Zoo ? I remember some types (arrays) just didn't work right.
```

– it doesn't take much to make things incompatible.  I took Microsoft's VTS example (listed above) and added the following to the V2 ApplicationCS example under "Person" class:

```
[OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]
    private List<HealthData> _healthDataList;
 public List<HealthData> HealthDataList
    {
        get { return _healthDataList; }
        set { _healthDataList = value; }
    }
```

HealthData is just defined as:

```
[Serializable]
public class HealthData
{
    #region Fields
    private int _weight;

    private int _height;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int Weight
    {
        get { return _weight; }
        set { _weight = value; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
        set { _height = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

This is enough to get the dreaded exception "... invalid number of fixups ...".

Curiously, if I just add a List of ints, all is well.  My questions are:

1. What causes Deserialization to fail?  How complex can the class structure be before things fail?  Apparently having a class that has a List of objects that are user defined classes is enough.  What else?
2. How can I fix things up?  Is there a way? It would be nice to know we can add new members and be able to read new serialized files with old copies of the software.
3. This post: [Deserialization backwards compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381928/deserialization-backwards-compatibility) suggests proto-buf.net as an alternative.  Would this handle the problem I've outlined here?  Does it have limitations?

My actual class structure is quite a bit more complicated than the Microsoft example, but I certainly do have Arrays and Lists<> of classes so this is a good thing to consider first.  But there may be other "gotchas" that the simple Microsoft example doesn't have.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Dave

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered a similar problem and I could not find a mention about these "gotchas"

Deserializing fails for the following reason:

The ObjectManager has a different logic to resolve dependencies for arrays and for reference and value types.

You added an array of new the reference type which is absent in your assembly (you have it labeled as the second version)

When ObjectManager attempts to resolve dependencies it builds the graph

When it sees the array, it can not fix it immediately, so that it creates a dummy reference and then fixes the array later

And since this type is not in the assembly, dependencies can't be resolved. 
For some reason, it does not remove the array from the list of elements for the fixes and at the end it throws an exception "IncorrectNumberOfFixups"

**For some reason, it throws an exception only for arrays of new reference types, so that if you use a collection of new structures rather than classes, everything will work correctly**

There are three ways to control serialization process, depending on how you can make changes to the old code or not:

1. Use Serialization Binder
2. Use Serizaliation Surrogates
3. **Use ISerialization. Suitable if you are unable to make changes to the old code and in the old code, you have not been controlled serialization process**

**You can use a simple solution, but it is not good.
Implement ISerializable and write that your array of new classes not serialized as an array of classes, but merely as a sequence of elements, outside the array**

So it will work correctly for the old version of the program

***A Helpful note:***

*In addition, you can fix this by using the second method, just use the array of structures or use the Dictionary, so as an each element in the Dictionary it is the structure*

An example of what you can do:
I don't recommend this method, but using this method, you will be able to maintain backward compatibility

```
[Serializable]
class NewItem
{
    public string Name;
}

[Serializable]
class Item : ISerializable
{
    [OptionalField]
    private List<NewItem> _newItems;

    public List<NewItem> NewItems
    {
        get { return _newItems; }
        set { _newItems = value; }
    }

    public Item()
    {

    }

    protected Item(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var newItemsSize = (int)info.GetValue("_newItemsSize", typeof(int));
        _newItems = new List<NewItem>(newItemsSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < newItemsSize; i++)
        {
            var item = (NewItem)info.GetValue($"_newItem{i}", typeof(NewItem));
            _newItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("_newItemsSize", _newItems.Count, typeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < _newItems.Count; i++)
            info.AddValue($"_newItem{i}", _newItems[i], typeof(NewItem));
    }
}
```