# C# - Adding a Byte Count Header to a BinaryFormatter Serialized Object

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I am writing a C# Server and Client. I want to send full serialized objects from the server to the client via a `NetworkStream`, and am attempting to use `BinaryFormatter` to this end. I call `BinaryFormatter.Serialize(...)` on the server. On the client, I am reading chunk by chunk from the `NetworkStream` into a `MemoryStream`. When I know I have the entire object in the `MemoryStream`, I deserialize using `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(...)`. This way I can avoid the `Deserialize` call blocking execution if there is nothing to deserialize.

The issue I've run into is that it is hard to determine when the entire object has been read into the `MemoryStream`. My ideal solution for this is to include a byte count for the serialized object before the object itself, i.e. the four bytes preceding the object represent an `Int32` for how many bytes the object is. However, `BinaryFormatter.Serialize` returns void, and I can't seem to find a reliable way to figure out how many bytes have been serialized by the call.

Is there an elegant way to determine how many bytes have been serialized by `BinaryFormatter.Serialize`, or an alternative method I could employ to achieve non-blocking deserialization calls?

Comment: It's really dangerous to use `BinaryFormatter` to exchange data between machines; the format changes depending on OS and .NET version, and there is no guarantee one version can decode another's. If you really want to go down that route investigate [Deserialze backward-compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381928), but in the long term you will be better off using a format you can actually control.

Comment: @DourHighArch Perhaps, but I think your warning and those on your supplied link are really for scenarios where the time between serialisation and deserialisation is long enough to allow for things like .NET patches; newer versions or essentially when the processes on either end are out of sync.  I don't believe this applies to the OP's case because 1) the byes are being pumped over the wire to a client app 2) time between serialisation and deserialisation is extremely small so as the problem of .NET version deltas ought not be a concern 3) OP has control over processes on either end

Comment: @DourHighArch 4) OP has control over which OS is supported 5) _"there is no guarantee one version can decode another's."_ - that also applies to say XML.    end)  I agree with you in medium to long term cases  if say the data was being persisted into say a database as mentioned by your link

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. When the `Serialize()` method returns, it's done. It's serialized your object. Even if that method returned a byte count, you wouldn't be able to prepend the serialized object's data with the byte count unless you serialize to a local buffer first instead of writing directly to the `NetworkStream`. And if you serialize into a local buffer (i.e. `MemoryStream`), then knowing the byte length is as simple as looking at the length of that local buffer after `Serialize()` returns. What is it you're actually having trouble with?

Comment: Adding to @DourHighArch's comment: when used to send data across networks, `BinaryFormatter` also introduces security issues.  Type information is embedded in the file itself, and the serializer constructs objects of the types specified in the file -- not the type you necessarily expect.  (This is in comparison to contract-based serializers where the receiving system specifies the types to deserialize.)  This allows malicious types -- such as those mentioned [here](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html) -- to be injected.

Comment: The risk can be ameliorated with a [custom serialization binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/controlling-serialization-and-deserialization-with-serializationbinder) -- but are you actually planning to do this?